# Shi Epoxidation Issues - Any help would be appreciated

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, organic-oxidation

As part of my PhD project, I'm currently looking into running a Shi Epoxidation reaction. The first step is to reproduce the current literature on this reaction by using *trans*-stilbene as my substrate. However, from the multitude of reaction conditions I have tried, none of them seem to work as described in the papers (very low to no conversion observed). I have tried the reaction conditions from the following papers:

1. "An Efficient Asymmetric Epoxidation Method for *trans*-Olefins Mediated by a Fructose-Derived Ketone" - the original Shi paper - using oxone as oxidant
2. "An Efficient Catalytic Asymmetric Epoxidation Method" - Shi - optimized conditions - using oxone as oxidant
3. "Asymmetric epoxidation using hydrogen peroxide ($\ce{H2O2}$) as primary oxidant" - Shi - using hydrogen peroxide as oxidant

The catalyst I have used in my reactions is the Shi Diketal Catalyst purchased from Sigma (https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/520160?lang=en&region=CA). What I've tried so far:

1. testing different batches of oxone, including titrating it and running test reactions ($\ce{aldehyde -> COOH}$ oxidation) - > 90% conversion observed
2. *trans*-stilbene + *m*-CPBA -> oxidized product is quantitative
3. I've left reactions run for > $\pu{6-24 h}$ with low conversion observed (< 30%).
4. $\mathrm{^{13}C}$ and $\mathrm{^{1}H}$ NMR of the catalyst show that it's clean

I am slowly running out of things to try out. It's weird because it's a published and highly used reaction ... If you have any experience with this reaction I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: What pH are you running your reactions at?

Comment: Please add proper citations to the papers so that they are easier to find.